# Populate form from XML json request using PHP and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, xml

This is not my area of expertise so I was wondering if any expert here would be able to get me on the right path.

I have access to an API that generates vehicle details based on the Registration Number.

The API looks something like this:

`https://example.com/xmlService/car.aspx?user=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&number=NO12345`

and generates XML data like this.

```
<vehicle>
    <message/>
    <regno>NO12345</regno>
    
    <make>SUZUKI</make>
    <vehcom>VITARA</vehcom>
    <color>White</color>
</vehicle>
```

Now here is the part I need help with, with a form similar to this i need to fetch and generate the Make, Type and Color "onChange" after i input the registration number in the regno field.

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    
    <label for="regno">Registration Nr.</label>
    <input id="regno" type="regno" name="regno" value="NO12345">
    
    <!-- Populate these fields -->
    
    <label for="make">Make</label>
    <input id="make" type="make" name="make" value="">
    
    <label for="vehcom">Type</label>
    <input id="vehcom" type="vehcom" name="vehcom" value="">
    
    <label for="color">Color</label>
    <input id="color" type="color" name="color" value="">
    
</form>
```

I've tried using CURL via PHP (api.php), but I'm 100% sure that I'm not even on the right path there.

```
<?php

$user = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASSWORD";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/xmlService/car.aspx?user=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&number=NO12345");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "XML=".$xmlcontent."&user=".$user."&password=".$password."&number=".$number.);
$content=curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($content);

?>
```

Trying to get some sort of response from jQuery using anything similar to this but here I'm also pretty sure I'm not on the right path ;(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $.ajax({
            'url': 'api.php',
            'type': 'GET',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'data': {'number': 'NO12345'},
            'success': function(response) {
              console.log(response);
            }
          });
  </script>
```

Any idea on getting me on the right path here ?, any help would be so MUCH APPRECIATED!

Comment: I'd do this with AJAX: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest Through rather than write the whole process myself, I'd also build it in a framework like AngularJS or React

Comment: `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);` you need to convert xml to array on response in curl.